# Language model gives different results when Bayes' theorem is applied

Tags: bayesian, natural-language, joint-distribution, language-models

Say, the following example is our corpus:

```
a quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Here, there are `9` tokens in the corpus. If we find the `unigram` probability for "a" it will be `P("a") = 1 / 9` and also `P("quick") = 1 / 9`.

Similarly if we take the bigram probability of `P("quick"|"a")`:

```
P("quick"|"a") = CountOf(How many times "quick" followed by "a") / CountOf("a")
               = 1 / 1
               = 1
```

But for `P("a"|"quick")` it is `0`.

Now we want to make an [n-gram language model](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejurafsky/slp3/3.pdf) `(n = 2)` and want to find the joint distribution of the phrase `"a quick"`, then according to the chain rule of probability:

```
P("a", "quick") = P("a")P("quick"|"a") = (1 / 9) * 1 = 1 / 9
```

Here, `P("quick"|"a")` means the probability of finding "quick" after "a".

But from `Bayes' theorem` we know:

```
P("a")P("quick"|"a") = P("quick")P("a"|"quick") = (1 / 9) * 0 = 0
```

But `P("quick")P("a"|"quick")` will give us `0` as `P("a"|"quick")` is `0`. Whereas, `P("a")P("quick"|"a")` is **not** `0`.

But mathematically they should be equal, but it is not happening. Moreover no matter how large corpus we take, the formulation found from `Bayes' theorem` will unlikely be exactly equal.

How we can describe this behavior? Is `joint distribution` order sensitive?

Comment: You appear to be confused by your notation, so it will help both you and your readers to explain what it means--particularly what the "P$ (\ \mid\ )$" really refers to and how you estimate these quantities from the corpus.

Comment: @whuber "P( ∣ )"  refers conditional probability.

Comment: Yes--but you do not reason with it as if it were.  I am trying to suggest that if you show us your definitions and calculations, you will both clarify your question and make it likely that you can answer it yourself.

Comment: This is a problem that shows up in an introductory-level class on natural language processing. You need to be extremely explicit about what $p(a \mid b)$ means here. Specifically, you need to clearly state what the random variables involved are: $p(A = a \mid B=b)$; clearly identify $A$ and $B$. By abbreviating the notation, you've obfuscated a crucial distinction.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy updated

Comment: My comment is in the same vein as whuber's. You're on the right track, and you need to go one step farther: What are the random variables? Take a look starting at slide 20 of [these course notes on probability](https://www.cs.jhu.edu/~jason/465/PowerPoint/lect04-prob-intro.ppt) from the NLP class I regularly TA. I'm trying not to give the answer away, because this is a question that shows up in class.

Comment: Again, the notation is what's tripping you up. I'll suggest that you write these as $P(X = a \mid Y = b)$ instead of just $P(a \mid b)$. It's a necessary step for you to catch the error in reasoning here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm turning my comments into an answer. Because this question shows up in the introductory natural language processing class I TA, I'm answering in the style for a [self-study](/questions/tagged/self-study) question. I hope any other answerers will respect this and do the same.

---

The notation is tripping you up here.
You need to be extremely explicit about what $p(a \mid b)$ means. Specifically, you need to clearly state what the random variables involved are: $P(A = a \mid B = b)$; clearly identify $A$ and $B$. By abbreviating the notation, you've obfuscated a crucial distinction.

You're on the right track, and you need to go one step farther: What are the random variables? Take a look starting at slide 20 of [these course notes on probability](https://www.cs.jhu.edu/%7Ejason/465/PowerPoint/lect04-prob-intro.ppt) from the NLP class at Johns Hopkins.

---

A final hint: consider representing the sentence as a sequence of random variates. Now, the probability distribution over sentences is a joint distribution:
$$
P(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, \ldots)
\text{.}
$$
How can we tie this to the $P(\text{"a"})$ and $P(\text{"quick"} \mid \text{"a"})$ values you wrote above, using the hint I gave earlier in my answer?

Comment: I think I got the point. It totally depends on from which side we give indices. In English we read text from left to right so it is indexed from left to right. And the the conflict I mentioned in the question won't exist if we re-indexed re-calculated everything from right to left for the second case and the values from both of cases would be the same. As from both sides "a" and "quick" (or, "quick" and "a") are adjacent maintaining the same probability.

Comment: Yes, precisely!